# I need a tool that can convert any speakers into wifi speakers

Tags: speakers

Basically I bought a pair of omni 10 speakers.

The sounds are great. However, the audio latency is 1000ms. I am using bluetooth to connect. Omni 10 doesn't have aptx.

I am looking for something like this

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00Z61YAAE?psc=1

Basically I want to connect my pc to my omni speakers using regular 3.5 mm. However, I don't want to use 3 m normal audio cable to connect my PC to OMNI 10. Doing so results in high delay.

I want my PC to connect to a wifi that then connect to the speaker using 3.5 mm cable. Is that even possible?

Can that be done? Will that reduce audio latency?

Basically it should turn any speakers with 3.5mm input into wireless speakers.

Update searching for turn speakers into wireless speakers yield this:

http://www.wired.com/2014/08/bluetooth-audio-adapters/

That sort of works. The problem is I already connect my omni 10 with bluetooth. I want to reduce the latency. I have also heard that streaming audio via wifi is much better than via bluetooth.

I "suspected" that this is what I need http://audioengineusa.com/Store/W3-Wireless-Audio-Adapter

Is it? I am not sure. It seems to use wifi. We connect something to computer with USB and then it plugs to my speakers using 3.5 mm.

Comment: Audio cables are almost always low-latency; they're just pure electrical signal. Wifi is basically guaranteed to give you much higher latency than cable alone. If you can cable it, do.

Comment: If I use 1m 3.5 mm cable I got 400 ms latency. If I use 3m cable the latency is 1000 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, check out [Chromecast Audio](https://www.google.ca/chromecast/speakers/). It might solve your problems.

As far as latency is concerned there shouldn't be *much*, but it is very hard to know the answer to this portion of the question without knowing all the variables, and there are **A LOT** when it comes to wireless frequencies, as I am sure you are aware.

Comment: Actually I read about chromecast audio. It says that it can do so via laptop. That is fine. Logically a desktop PC with a wifi adapater like mine should work too. I got internet from wifi. I should be able to stream audio from wifi. I just want to make sure.

Comment: Can chromecast audio allow me to play video games? Basically can it works as a speaker for all purpose or can it only sing a few songs with special software and that's it

Comment: There are applications you can get for your PC to stream any and all audio to the speakers, so yes it is possible, but again, latency will be your only concern. It might be difficult to find anything that will cut the latency down to an acceptable level when you're using wireless frequencies. Here is a link to a PC software that will allow you to stream any and all audio from your PC though, [Chromecast Audio Stream](https://github.com/acidhax/chromecast-audio-stream)

Comment: I would like to add to Steviet answer

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-send-your-computers-audio-to-a-chromecast-1750297581

    On Windows, you need Chromecast Audio Stream. Once it’s installed, just select your Chromecast from the tray icon and your audio will start streaming.

    That’s it, now all your computer’s audio should be routed through the Chromecast. This should work for everything from iTunes to video games to random MP3s you’re playing from a folder.